# Spring Cloud Contract Debugging

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

Im new to Spring Cloud contract. I have written the groovy contract but the wiremock tests are failing. All I see in the console is

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[2]00> but was:<[4]00>

Can anyone please guide me how to enable more debugging ad also is there a way to print the request and response sent by wiremock?
I have set the logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=DEBUG in my spring boot app but no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of the latest version of sc-contract, WireMock should print exactly what wasn't matched. You can also read the documentation over here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Finchley.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud.html#_how_can_i_debug_the_request_response_being_sent_by_the_generated_tests_client where we answer your questions in more depth. Let me copy that part for you

> 86.8 How can I debug the request/response being sent by the generated tests client? The generated tests all boil down to RestAssured in some
>   form or fashion which relies on Apache HttpClient. HttpClient has a
>   facility called wire logging which logs the entire request and
>   response to HttpClient. Spring Boot has a logging common application
>   property for doing this sort of thing, just add this to your
>   application properties
>
> logging.level.org.apache.http.wire=DEBUG
>   86.8.1 How can I debug the mapping/request/response being sent by WireMock? Starting from version 1.2.0 we turn on WireMock logging to
>   info and the WireMock notifier to being verbose. Now you will exactly
>   know what request was received by WireMock server and which matching
>   response definition was picked.
>
> To turn off this feature just bump WireMock logging to ERROR
>
> logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=ERROR
>   86.8.2 How can I see what got registered in the HTTP server stub? You can use the mappingsOutputFolder property on @AutoConfigureStubRunner
>   or StubRunnerRule to dump all mappings per artifact id. Also the port
>   at which the given stub server was started will be attached.
>
> 86.8.3 Can I reference text from file? Yes! With version 1.2.0 we’ve added such a possibility. It’s enough to call file(…​) method in the
>   DSL and provide a path relative to where the contract lays. If you’re
>   using YAML just use the bodyFromFile property.

Comment: Sorry about not mentioning about the version.. Im on 1.2.4.RELEASE. I turned on both logging.level.org.apache.http.wire and logging.level.com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock=DEBUG

Comment: Just to add to the above. I still dont see any logs even after enabling it

Comment: In `1.2.x` the WireMock version was not updated to the one that was dumping the information to logs. You can debug the response from WireMock cause with 404 there should be the whole body that provides a lot of debug info